# how to parse json data in php

Tags: php, json, opencart

I have json result from API like:

```
 { 
 "pagination": 
 { 
 "results" : 2248, 
 "page" : 1, 
 "page_size" : 200, 
 **"pages" : 12** 
 }, 

 "products" : 
 [  {"id": "370c3876-a2b9-11e2-b2b4-bc764e10976c", "source_id": "",....}]}
```

I would like to retrieve **"pages" :   12** from **pagination**. How can I do it?

Comment: Where you want to access?. At client side or at server side???

Comment: it is from server side

Comment: Then see my answer below. It will work

Comment: it shows or return empty

Comment: Please paste your json response here http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and check whether it's a valid json response

Comment: JSON
pagination
results : 2251
page : 2
page_size : 200
pages : 12
products
0
1
2
3
4

Comment: i already use this api

Comment: If your result is like this then my solution should work. It is working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this and it worked fine

```
$data = ' { 
 "pagination": 
 { 
 "results" : 2248, 
 "page" : 1, 
 "page_size" : 200, 
 "pages" : 12
 }
}';
$response = json_decode($data, true);

echo $response['pagination']['pages'];//12
```

Comment: it shows empty  $out = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $out;

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_decode` to decode the api response, then access the property.

Example:

```
$response = json_decode($data, true);
echo $response['pagination']['pages'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$object = json_decode($your_api_return_string);

$pages = $object->pagination->pages;

echo $pages;

?>
```